# Wifi direct connection between several devices

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

Imagine this scenario:

AndroidA knows AndroidB but doesn't know Android C.

AndroidB knows AndroidC and Android A.

Is it possible to connect Android A to Android C using AndroidB with WifiDirect?
Like a electrical circuit in series.

**Update:**
AndroidC and AndroidB are sensors, and i need to pass to AndroidA the GPS localization (latitude/longitude) and a flag.
Only AndroidA has communication with the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible.

To do this, you have to do the following:

1. Call WiFiP2PManager "Connect" from Android A to Android B, make sure to set the WifiP2pConfig "groupOwnerIntent" to 0 (which will make sure that Android B will become the group owner).
2. Do the same from Android C to Android B, Connect with "groupOwnerIntent" equals to 0 (now we have the same group for the 3 devices and Android B is the Owner / Server / Manager).
3. Start Sockets server at Android B, and connect to it from A and C via sockets.
4. At Android B, when receiving a message or data from Android A, forward it to Android C (or all connected devices / act as a broadcast server).

Goodluck.